# Add a custom field in Woocommerce Edit Account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, account

I have custom checkout fields `favorite_color` that users can fill in during checkout *(not required)*,imilar to other default checkout fields...

In My Account section in "Edit Account", I Would like to add `favorite_color` custom field to allow customer editing this field value.

For that I have edited the template `myaccount/form-edit-account.php` by copying and editing an original line of code in it:

```
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
    <label for="account_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
</p>
```

I replaced the **account_first_name** with my **favorite_color** and the field even shows the saved value in the field (thanks to `$user->favorite_color`)

But the bad part is, it does not get saved.

What code must I add to get this working and getting saved?

The original template code is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Edit account form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.6.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php _e( 'Password change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_current"><?php _e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_1"><?php _e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_2"><?php _e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details' ); ?>
        <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
```

Comment: Ideally you should insert this via one of the action hooks called in this template, rather than by modifying the template itself.

Comment: I just want the user to change the custom checkout field (in my example i named it "favorite_color").  What code do I have to add to the form-edit-account.php?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This can be done without overriding template files, just using available hooks this way:

```
// Add the custom field "favorite_color"
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'add_favorite_color_to_edit_account_form' );
function add_favorite_color_to_edit_account_form() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="favorite_color"><?php _e( 'Favorite color', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="favorite_color" id="favorite_color" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->favorite_color ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}

// Save the custom field 'favorite_color' 
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_favorite_color_account_details', 12, 1 );
function save_favorite_color_account_details( $user_id ) {
    // For Favorite color
    if( isset( $_POST['favorite_color'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorite_color', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['favorite_color'] ) );

    // For Billing email (added related to your comment)
    if( isset( $_POST['account_email'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_email', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_email'] ) );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme) or in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

> If you want to override the template to display the custom field, you just have to keep the 2nd hooked function (the one who saves the data when edited).

Comment: Thanks, it is working.

However, is it possible to update the billing_email and account_email at the same time? Because, with the standard code it is just editing the account_email, not the billing_email.

Is there a "trick" so it does also edit the billing_email at the same time?

-Jo

Comment: Thank you, if you don't mind another question: Is it also possible to add a custom field, "Favorite Color 2"? . i tried adding it but it is not working, something i am doing wrong

Comment: yes i asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604357/issue-when-adding-an-additional-custom-field-in-woocommerce-edit-account-page

Comment: How to sort this field before Change Password Fieldset? Any idea?