# Adding some my account custom fields to admin user pages in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-data

In another question on here a user asked [How to add a custom fields in Edit Account page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604357/adding-an-additional-custom-field-in-woocommerce-edit-account-page)

I am looking to do the same thing but also to add the same custom field on the users profile page where its visible to an Administrator. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated** - To add those two "Favorite color" custom fields in Wordpress admin user pages, you will use the following:

```
// Add the custom field "favorite_color" in admin user
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_custom_user_data', 1, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_custom_user_data', 1, 1 );
function add_extra_custom_user_data( $user )
{
    ?>
        <h3><?php _e("Other details",'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="favorite_color"><?php _e( 'Favorite color', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="favorite_color" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'favorite_color', $user->ID )); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <th><label for="favorite_color2"><?php _e( 'Favorite color 2', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="favorite_color2" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'favorite_color2', $user->ID )); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    <?php
}

// Save the custom field 'favorite_color' in admin user
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_custom_user_data' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_custom_user_data' );
function save_extra_custom_user_data( $user_id )
{
    if( ! empty($_POST['favorite_color']) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorite_color', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['favorite_color'] ) );

    if( ! empty($_POST['favorite_color2']) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'favorite_color2', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['favorite_color2'] ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]