# Add/update fields on My Account page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to create My Account page for registered users with changeable fields on backend and frontend.

Now the fields are updated if I change the values through the admin panel. However, if I change the field values through My Account, the fields are not saved or updated.

What do i need to change or add to the code?

I used the following LoicTheAztec's answers:

[Add a custom field in Woocommerce Edit Account page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599050/add-a-custom-field-in-woocommerce-edit-account-page)

[Adding some my account custom fields to admin user pages in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51970353/adding-some-my-account-custom-fields-to-admin-user-pages-in-woocommerce)

[Adding an additional custom field in Woocommerce Edit Account page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604357/adding-an-additional-custom-field-in-woocommerce-edit-account-page)

**My code:**

1. Template:

```html
$user = wp_get_current_user();

<form class="tabs-content__page_inner woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post" 
     <div class="pers-acc__tab-fields_field tab-field woocommerce-form-row form-row">
          <label for="account_phone" class="tab-field__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Телефон', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
          <div class="tab-field__input-inner">
               <input type="text" class="tab-field__input woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_phone" id="account_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->account_phone ); ?>" />
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

2. functions.php

```html
<?php
add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_phone_number_account_details', 20, 1);
function save_phone_number_account_details($user_id) {
    if( isset( $_POST['account_phone'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_phone'] ) );
    }
}

//custom field in admin console
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_extra_custom_user_data', 1, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_extra_custom_user_data', 1, 1 );
function add_extra_custom_user_data( $user )
{
?>
<h3><?php _e("Other details",'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
         <table class="form-table">
             <tr>
                 <th><label for="account_phone"><?php _e( 'Custom phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                 <td><input type="text" name="account_phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_author_meta( 'account_phone', $user->ID )); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
         <br />
     <?php
}

//save custom field value in admin console
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_custom_user_data' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_custom_user_data' );
function save_extra_custom_user_data( $user_id )
{
    if( ! empty($_POST['account_phone']) )
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_phone', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_phone'] ) );
}
```

Comment: The save function should be working fine, `$user->account_phone` is the issue, I guess. You need to call the `get_user_meta` function to get the user metadata.

Comment: Do you mean replace `$user->account_phone` to `get_user_meta($user->ID, 'account_phone', true)`? If so, the result hasn't changed. 
If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, `get_user_meta($user->ID, 'account_phone', true)` is correct if that doesn't display the field data, then You might be doing something wrong with your custom field display code. Can you please why you have the `form` tag in your **Template:** code and did you use the hook to add a custom field to my account page or did you copy the template file in the child theme and added the HTML code in the template file in child theme?

Comment: I am learning to develop my own Woocommerce theme. So I copied the fields template from the `form-edit-account.php` file into my own page template where I'm working on it. I take the `<form>` tag from default `form-edit-account.php`

Comment: I adding HTML code to my template. I also tried adding my custom fields using hooks, but the result didn't change

Comment: I don't fully understand how you're using those fields. but if you're saying you have your own edit account page which is different from the WooCommerce my account > Edit account details page then form submission might not work, I guess.