# Trying to add woo commerce shipping country and state drop down to custom account page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am quite new to working with PHP.

I am trying to add woo commerce country and state drop down to custom user account page.

- I need to get the users country and state from usermeta (checkout
  page shipping details)
- I need to display these on the account page,
  so user can edit them if they want - press update button to save the
  updated country and state to the same usermeta key.
- Also if the user
  changes the country in the drop down I need the state options to
  change corresponding to the country choosen.

Just wondering what code I would need for this?

I think I can get the country dropdown to appear by:

```
<?php
global $woocommerce;    
woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_country', array( 'type' => 'country' ) );
?>
```

But I am not sure how to get the existing usermeta data for billing country

Not sure how to get it to update

Not sure how to get state to appear and how to get the state dropdown options to change with what country is chosen.

Thanks in advance

---

Thanks JayDev - I reviewed the page link but that seems to be using hooks specific to the woo commerce account page. I am building a custom page.

From the link you sent and the custom page we already have I tried this but it did not seem to work. Any Ideas?

I tried the following but it did not seem to work .. any ideas?

in function.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_account_details_information', 'account_details_information' );   
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_account_details_information', 'account_details_information' ); 

function account_details_information(){
    $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
    $first_name=get_user_meta($user_id,'first_name',true);
    $last_name=get_user_meta($user_id,'last_name',true);
    $dob=get_user_meta($user_id,'birthday',true);
    $gender=get_user_meta($user_id,'gender',true);
    if($gender=="unknown"){
    $gender=    "Prefer not to say";
    }
    $phone=get_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_phone_number',true);
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    $email=$user_info->user_email;
    $address1=get_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_address_1',true);
    $address2=get_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_address_2',true);
    $country=get_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_country',true);
    $state=get_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_region',true);
    $city=get_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_city',true);
    $shipping_zip_code=get_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_zip_code',true);
    $add=$address1.' '.$address2.' '.$city.' '.$state.' '.$shipping_zip_code;
    $result=array('first_name'=>$first_name,'last_name'=>$last_name,'dob'=>$dob,'gender'=>$gender,
    'phone'=>$phone,'address'=>$add,'email'=>$email,'address_1'=>$address1,'address_2'=>$address2,
    'country'=>$country,'state'=>$state,'city'=>$city,'zipcode'=>$shipping_zip_code);
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
    
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_account_details_information_save', 'account_details_information_save' );   
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_account_details_information_save', 'account_details_information_save' ); 

function account_details_information_save(){
    $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
        update_user_meta($user_id,'first_name',$_POST['first_name']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'last_name',$_POST['last_name']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'birthday',$_POST['dob']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'gender',$_POST['gender']);
        
        update_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_address_1',$_POST['address_1']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_address_2',$_POST['address_2']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_country',$_POST['country']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_region',$_POST['state']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_city',$_POST['city']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_zip_code',$_POST['zipcode']);
        update_user_meta($user_id,'shipping_phone_number',$_POST['phone']);
        $result=array('code'=>200);
        echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}
```

in custom page.php

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $woocommerce; 

?>


<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="shipping_country">Country</label>

<label for="shipping_country"><?php  woocommerce_form_field( 'shipping_country', array( 'type' => 'country' ) ); ?></label>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer on this question may be able to help you. It tells you how to add a field and save it on the edit account page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47599050/add-a-custom-field-in-woocommerce-edit-account-page

Comment: @JayDev95 - Thanks . As we are trying to add the country and state field to a custom page - I tried the code above (in edited question) but it did not work. Any ideas? Also do you know how we could connect the state field to populate with the country field that is chosen.

Thanks

Comment: You have to edit users saved address and there is template for that - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-edit-address.php . Dont reinvent the wheel :)